# Ctrl+Alt+T doesn't open Terminal (Compiz related?)

Tags: compiz, command-line, shortcut-keys

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> doesn't open the Terminal, and I'm pretty sure it's got something to do with Compiz.

Compiz disabled the transparency on my launcher (using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with Unity) and so I uninstalled it.

But after I uninstalled Compiz, my UI was messed up, so I reinstalled it. Now <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> doesn't open the Terminal.

**System Settings >> Keyboard >> Shortcuts** has the shortcut to terminal there, but it simply does not work.

What should I do?

Comment: After I uninstalled Compiz and restarted my laptop, Ctrl+Alt+T still worked. It stopped working after I installed Compiz again.

Comment: In the CCSM you have a Gnome Compatibility section, in there you set the use of that Key combination to show the Terminal, amongst other things , the reason is Metacity/Mutter have this key binded to show the Terminal, Compiz does not, although in Unity it *should* bring the Terminal by default.

Answer (score 2):

You can click on the Shortcut combination showing in the **System Settings** -> **Keyboard** -> **Shortcuts** and reassign the key.

Hope this will help.

If you have `compizconfig-settings-manager` installed, you can reset the profile by going to the preference section of the program and clicking on **Reset to defaults** button.

Answer (score 2):

You can try starting the terminal manually, e.g. from xterm and see what the output is.

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and then enter "xterm" to get an xterm.

There, simply type "GNOME Terminal" to try to start the terminal.

or try to edit the `/etc/default/locale`

Solution:'`nano /etc/default/locale`' back to the defaultc contents of that file to:

```
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LANGUAGE="en_US"
```