# Ctrl + Alt + T doesn't work anymore

Tags: 18.04, shortcut-keys

After installing Unity desktop on my Ubuntu 18.04 the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> shortcut to launch the terminal stopped working for no reason. I already tried different times to reset to default and manually set the shortcut to the command, and restarting the system, but it still doesn't work. Does someone have any idea?

Comment: Do not know if this link will help, but might give you ideas.  Imagine you checked keyboard short cuts settings, maybe reinstall terminal.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/151883/ctrlaltt-doesnt-open-terminal-compiz-related?rq=1

Comment: Unfortunately nothing of what's suggested in that question helped @crip659

Comment: Is it just on unity, or is the there a problem on gnome also?

Comment: I worked as long as I used gnome

Comment: I would try reinstalling unity, it does work with my unity on 19.10, so thinking something did not install perfectly first time.